# Babel code throwing Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Having a strange issue occur when using babel to trans-compile ES6 into ES5.

The issue I'm having seems to be unrelated to [Babel/RequireJS + typeof "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35392666/babel-requirejs-typeof-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded)

If you run this trivial code snippet with the [default settings on babeljs.io](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2)

```
class Person {

  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

  set name(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  set age(age) {
    this.age = age;
  }

  get name() {
    return this.name;
  }

  get age() {
    return this.age;
  }

}

let person = new Person('John Doe', 25);

console.log(person.name);
```

You get **Maximum call stack size exceeded** as an error. I'm not sure why this is. According to [this github issue](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/3836) the issue was resolved?

I've been able to drill it down to this line in ES5 code:

```
 set: function set(name) { ... }
```

But I'm not sure why I'm getting the error. Can anyone clarify what's going on here or what a workaround is?

**Note:** I've replicated this issue on jsfiddle, codepen, jsbin, and js.do. Each time I try to set a `debugger;` the console crashes so I can't inspect the callstack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That error is actually unrelated to Babel, regular ES6 will also blowout the stack, meaning Babel is producing correct behavior.

```js
// regular ES6, no babel
class Person {

  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  set name(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  get name() {
    return this.name;
  }
}

let person = new Person('John Doe');
```

Your getters/setters cannot have the same name as the property they are manipulating because they will end up calling themselves infinitely.

```
get name() {
  return this.name; // call the getter again which calls it again which calls it again ...
}

set name(name) {
  this.name = name; // call the setter again which calls it again which calls it again ...
}
```

If you just change the property name (for example `_name` instead of `name`), everything works:

```js
class Person {

  constructor(name, age) {
    this._name = name;
  }

  set name(name) {
    this._name = name;
  }

  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }
}

let person = new Person('John Doe');

console.log(person.name); // 'John Doe'
```